# Why this driver cannot start?

Tags: windows-7, android

What does this mean?

[image: properties dialog]

Is it my Samsung Galaxy 1? I'm having trouble with connecting it with Samsung Kies. When I start Samsung Kies, this is what happens when I connect the phone, it loops forever and the restore driver is not working:

[image: screen shot]

[image: screen shot]

### Update

This started working again after resettting everything. Now I can use Samsung Kies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are your drivers up to date? What exactly are you trying to do? According to [this question and its answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118427/cant-debug-android-this-device-cannot-start-code-10) this might be related to the Developer Settings of Android.

Never had that error message with my Android tablet, although I have the Android SDK with the updated USB drivers installed (and I have USB debugging enabled).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'm trying to connect my Samsung ggalazy 1 phone to a Sony Vaio laptop. I've updated the question with how my program loops when I try to connect the phone. i'm nearly certain that this is the same problem and an Android issue.

Comment: It should be save to ignore the actual programs for now as long as the device entry isn't showing up without an error. Are you using the stock cable and a proper USB port (e.g. USB 2 rather than 1.0/1.1)?

Comment: Yes, everything with the hardware seems alright and it even works with another computer though this error was also intermittent there for a while. I'm just trying different combination of al settings now, fiddling in the device manager trying to get contact with the phone. It's really good when it actually works and I suspect this is just a software setting, some IRQ or likewise.

Comment: Now for some reason it just started working. Seemingly random after resettting everything and using as normal. Might have to do with some setting on the phone such as not closing a running program or likewise. Anyhow now I can use Samsung kies the way I want in the latest version. THanks for the help.